# Collapse sidebar items on macOS SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui, swiftui-list

When attempting to replicate the behaviour of Finder and SF Symbols in a macOS application using SwiftUI, I encountered difficulties with DisclosureGroup.

Here is my current code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SidebarView: View {
    @State private var companiesExpanded = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: $companiesExpanded) {
                NavigationLink(destination: CompaniesLibraryView()) {
                    Label("Water", systemImage: "drop")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: CompaniesLibraryView()) {
                    Label("Sewage", systemImage: "toilet")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: CompaniesLibraryView()) {
                    Label("Electricity", systemImage: "bolt")
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Companies")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, I attempted to use the DisclosureGroup to create collapsible sections in the sidebar, similar to what is seen in Finder and SF Symbols. However, the result is not the same. The DisclosureGroup does collapse the items, but it lacks the visual appearance and behaviour of Finder's sidebar.

I would greatly appreciate any help to achieve the desired behaviour. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Finder collapse items (Goal):
[image]

SF Symbols (Goal):
[image]

My App (Actual):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proposal to fix some of the issues.

- align `Label` left with a `.frame(..)`, `.infinity` will make all Labels take the space of the whole sidebar.
- `Label` color `.primary`
- give a little padding for the `label`
- `label` color `.secondary`
- stabilize the animation with a `Spacer` at the bottom

  ```
    import SwiftUI

    struct SidebarView: View {
    @State private var companiesExpanded = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: $companiesExpanded) {
                NavigationLink(destination: CompaniesLibraryView()) {
                    Label("Water", systemImage: "drop")
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: CompaniesLibraryView()) {
                    Label("Sewage", systemImage: "star")
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: CompaniesLibraryView()) {
                    Label("Electricity", systemImage: "bolt")
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Companies")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    .padding(5)
            }
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    }
  ```

You can have more control with a custom [DisclosureGroupStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/disclosuregroupstyle).

For example:
[How to make a custom DisclosureGroup (drop down) in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73368328/16157878)

Answer (score 0):

By adding `.frame` with `alignment: .top` to the `DisclosureGroup()`, the `DisclosureGroup()` will always be pushed to the top and won't be centred again after closing.

```swift
struct SidebarView: View {
    @State private var companiesExpanded = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: $companiesExpanded) {
                NavigationLink(destination: CompaniesLibraryView()) {
                    Label("Water", systemImage: "drop")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: CompaniesLibraryView()) {
                    Label("Sewage", systemImage: "toilet")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: CompaniesLibraryView()) {
                    Label("Electricity", systemImage: "bolt")
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Companies")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
            }
            .frame(height: 100, alignment: .top) // Push DisclosureGroup() to the top
            .background(.gray) // To see frame
        }
    }
}
```